# Pytest testing for class value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Doing a basic implementation of a binary tree in python and testing the implementation using pytest. One of the unit test is to check if the new node is inserted properly to the left (or the right) of the parent node. When I do the assert statement is shows the correct comparison on the left and on the right of the == but tails me the test failed. Snippets of code is attached.

### Relevant part of the main code:

```
class Node:
    # Contains data variables.
    def __init__(self, val: Optional[int]=None) -> None:
        self.value: Optional[int] = val
        self.left: Optional[Node] = None
        self.right: Optional[Node] = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.value}"

    def insert(self, data: int) -> bool:
        # Insert a node to the right or left of a parent node.
        # Return False only if trying to insert duplicate.

        if self.value == data:      # Duplicate found
            return False

        if self.value > data:       # New node to the left of parent node
            if self.left:           # If left exist, then recurse
                return self.left.insert(data)
            self.left = Node(data)  # Default, create a new left node
            return True
        else:
            if self.right:          # If right exist, then recurse
                return self.right.insert(data)
            self.right = Node(data) # Default, create a new right node
            return True
```

### Specific pytest unit test

```
def test_node_insert_left():
    node = Node(4)
    node.insert(3)
    #print(f"\n{node.left}-{node}-{node.right}")

    assert node.value == 4
    assert node.left == Node(3)             # I've also tried node.left == 3
    assert type(node.left) == type(Node())
    assert node.right == None
```

### The error message

```
> assert node.left == Node(3)
E       assert 3 == 3
E         -3
E         +3
```

Comment: Your code would be easier to debug if the `repr` of your Node was (for instance) `f'Node({self.value})'` so you can distinguish nodes from the things they contain.

Comment: But if you want two nodes to show as equal, you should implement `__eq__` in your Node class.

Answer (score 0):

Two nodes will not equal unless you implement `__eq__` in your node class.

You could write an `__eq__` method in `Node`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Node):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.value==other.value
```

if you want to regard any two nodes holding the same value as equal.

Then `assert node.left == Node(3)` would work.

However, sinces nodes contain more than just a value, that might not be ideal.

---

More simply:

For your assertion, what you actually want to test is that the node holds the value 3. For that, you could simply change your assertion to

```
assert node.left.value == 3
```